# m2eclipse + wtp + jboss deploying the wrong file

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, ear, eclipse-wtp

I'm using maven2 with eclipse for an ear project with multiple war, ejb and jar files.
   My application server is JBoss 4.2.3.

Using the maven in command line i can obtain a correct packaging for my ear. It runs in my test and production severs without a problem. But running it by command line is very troublesome in everyday development. So, I decide to give a try to m2eclipse and the m2e-extra integration with wtp but I got stuck.

As it seems, wtp is generating a ear (i can't finde how or where) but I know it's results end up in a folder (.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0) this result is packaged by the jboss323.xml script.

The thing is, I don't know how WTP is generating the results of this folder (tmp0) but i know it is not from my pom.xml. One of the hints is that I have two jars that are internal projects referenced by my pom, they are corectly packaged by maven command line, but missing by the WTP output.

I've tryed many different configurations and none of them proved to make it use my pom.xml to generate the output to WTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've tryed many alternatives and it kept leaving some jar out of the ear.

Now with m2e in eclipse Indigo the problem was kind of solved.
It seems was a bug only fixed in this version.